# nHibernate transaction logging

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nhibernate, transaction-log

Our application uses nHibernate, and there is a requirement to log all changes to a certain table. I don't need to log the entire queries generated by the ORM, just the data and the date.

For example, let's say I have an entity called Employee:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The only solution I can think of is manually keeping track of changes (new, updated and deleted entities) and logging that data to a table. Something along the lines of:

```
public void SaveEmployees(List<Employee> employees)
{
    employees.ForEach(x => {
        if (x.ID == 0) // add do LOG list as new
        else // add to LOG list as old
    });

    // save employees like usual
    // save LOG list
}
```

This isn't difficult to do, even with fetching the old data to see what's missing, but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Comment: As you said you do not want to log the queries. Just in case you choose that option, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54480679/5779732) is the way explained.

Comment: Transaction logs have nothing to do with NHibernate. You are asking about *auditing* and typically, it's something you do in the *database*, not a client-side ORM tool. All major databases have auditing or change tracking mechanisms that can be used to audit data changes

Comment: Which database are you targeting? For example, in SQL Server you can use the built-in auditing feature, you can use change tracking to periodically pick and store changes or, in SQL Server 2017 and later, you can use temporal tables to track changes in a history table

Answer (score 0):

I think an `Interceptor` might give you what you need. You can use the `OnFlushDirty()` or the `OnSave()` method to write your changes. Documentation [here](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-interceptors).